# В чем разница в передаваемом параметре функции для C++?

Tags: c++

В чем разница между записями:

```
int32_t Function1(const int32_t c);
int32_t Function2(const int32_t &c);
int32_t &Function3(const int32_t &c);
```

Comment: первая работает  копией, вторая с самым объектом, третья является ссылкой на объект, все три не изменяют объект

Comment: Вас интересует конкретно тип `int32_t`, или вообще передача по значению/ссылке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае передаёте константу по значению:

```
int32_t Function1(const int32_t c);
```

Во втором - ссылку на константу:

```
int32_t Function2(const int32_t &c);
```

В третьем - ссылку на константу + возвращается ссылка на неконстанту:

```
int32_t &Function3(const int32_t &c);
```

То есть между 2 и 3 нет разницы в передаваемом параметре, а между 1 и 2/3 - есть.

Comment: @OnuchinVA задайте новый вопрос с кодом, а не изменяйте старый